# Display Object in HTML table ng-repeat - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, grid, angularjs-ng-repeat

My Object looks like this

```
Object
    207T : Object
        metal : 1
        steel : 2
    205T : Object
        metal : 1
        steel : 3
    208T : Object
        metal : 1
        steel : 3
    209T : Object
        metal : 0
        steel : 9
```

Now this object i need to display in below format

```
207T, 205T, 208T, 209T  should be in table heading which is fine

<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th ng-repeat="(key, value) in mainObj">{{key}}</th>
</tr>
```

And then the format should be

[image]

How to acheive this

Answer (score 2):

We can not create table column wise so in this case best and cleanest way would be to filter out the row values and using them inside view. So
In controller

```
app.controller(['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.object= values;

  $scope.valuesMetal= [];
  $scope.valuessteel = [];
  // initializing row values for use in the using in view

  angular.forEach(values, function(value, key) {
     $scope.valuesMetal.push(value.metal );
     $scope.valuessteel.push(value.metal );
  }); 
}]);
```

In the view   we just display our values

```
<tr>
    <th ng-repeat="(key, value) in mainObj">{{key}}</th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td >Metal</td>
    <td  ng-repeat="(key, value) in valuesMetal" >{{value}}</td>

</tr>

<tr>
    <td >steel</td>
    <td  ng-repeat="(key, value) in valuessteel" >{{value}}</td>

</tr>

<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the header you need to convert the object to array:

```
// inside controller
mainObjArray = Object.keys(mainObj); // ['207T', '205T', '208T', '209T']
```

// header html

```
<tr>
     <th ng-repeat="key in mainObjArray">{{key}}</th>
</tr>
```

And for the rest of values you can do some like:

```
// inside controller
mainObjValues = mainObjArray.map(function(item){
  return mainObj[item];
}); // output: [{metal: 1, steel: 2}, {...}]
```

Then the body-table:

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in mainObjValues">
   <td>{{item.metal}}</td>
   <td>{{item.steel}}</td>
   ....
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
var sampleObj = {  
   "207T":{  
      "metal":1,
      "steel":2
   },
   "205T":{  
      "metal":1,
      "steel":3
   },
   "208T":{  
      "metal":1,
      "steel":3
   },
   "209T":{  
      "metal":0,
      "steel":9
   }
}
 $scope.metal = [];
 $scope.steel= []
$scope.keys = Object.keys(sampleObj);

angular.forEach(sampleObj, function(obj) {
     $scope.metal.push(obj.metal );
     $scope.steel.push(obj.steel );
  }); 

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<table>
 
 <tr>
    <th ng-repeat="item in keys">{{item}}</th> 
</tr> 
<tr>
    <td >Metal</td>
    <td  ng-repeat="item in metal track by $index" >{{item}}</td>

</tr>

<tr>
    <td >Steel</td>
    <td  ng-repeat="item in steel track by $index" >{{item}}</td>

</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually simple.

```
    <table>
    <tr>    
        <th></th>
        <th ng-repeat="(key, value) in mainObj">{{key}}</th>
    </tr>
```

Here you are ng repeating in th, will display 207t, 205T etc

```
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">    
        <td ng-repeat="item1 in item track by $index">{{item[$index]}}</td>            
    </tr>
```

Here you have to `ng repeat tr`, so that it will display `metal` and `steel`. and then each `td` u have to `ng repeat` and should display with index `item[$index]`